# 2014 Election Results: Congratulations to the new moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The [2014 elections](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5) are over. Analyzing the [OpenSTV file](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/5) (you may view an online summary report [here](http://www.opavote.org/results/5757331467927552/0) as well) the results are as follows (with no particular order):

[image: Jyrki Lahtonen]
[image: Pedro Tamaroff]
[image: Daniel Fischer]

At the same time, I'd like to thank our departing moderators, [Alex Becker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8173/alex-becker) and [Willie Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1543/willie-wong), for their long and hard work over the years!

Comment: [You did not disappoint me.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19229741#19229741)

Comment: @quid: I have a long standing tradition by now. :-P

Comment: I was going to try to beat you, but I forgot to download OpenSTV first. :(

Comment: "No particular order"? It's clearly north to south.

Comment: It says the the data is for Mac or Windows only. What if I use Linux and want to see it?

Comment: @dustin: Buy a Windows 8.1 tablet hybrid, and use that.

Comment: Guess it's time for me to occupy this post.

Comment: @Grace: I've beat Shog twice now with these announcements (once here, once on MathOverflow), so it's nothing new. As I said, tradition. :-)

Comment: I'd like to wish a fond farewell to two moderators who are stepping down this year. They have both done a lot for the community, as both moderator and trusted user. Willie Wong has been supporting this community since its very birth in 2010, and has served as a moderator elected in the site's very first election. Alex Becker has been a strong member of the community since 2011, and has been acting as a moderator since the 2013 moderator election. They've done great by this community, and I wish them a great future.

Comment: It is a usual courtesy to give a new commander 100 days of grace before starting to criticize their commanding abilities. Let's give the new moderators these 100 days of grace before we start making claims about their moderating abilities. Shall we?

Comment: @dustin Under Linux, install the `openstv` package from your distribution (it's the same software, but the original authors stopped releasing it under a free license at some point) — if your distribution lacks the package, you can get it from e.g. [Ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/openstv), or you can check out the [source](https://github.com/OpenTechStrategies/openstv). Download the [results file](http://math.stackexchange.com/election/download-result/5), rename it to have a `.blt` extension, and run `openstv-run-election MeekSTV 5.blt`.

Comment: Congratulations also from your wooden-medal rival :D

Comment: Congratulations on your newfound positions! May your sanity hold out for as long as possible.

Comment: @Asaf Does the usual courtesy specify whether these have to be the *first* 100 days? Or can we criticize them now if we promise not to do so for 100 not-necessarily consecutive days later?

Comment: @Meelo: First 100 days. Sorry. :-)

Comment: I'm going to break the convention and immediately begin criticizing @DanielFischer for being the only mod with an identicon as avatar.

Comment: @Behaviour: It's a method for differentiating between Daniel and Arthur Fischer. :-)

Comment: I consider my identicon an important part of my personality and support Daniel's choice.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You were my first choice. Better luck next time.

Comment: @Meelo: Asaf's comment says "...100 days of grace **before** starting to criticize..."[emphasis added]

Comment: Very happy with the results! These three were my top 3 at the very beginning of the primary voting. Looking forward to an even better community. Privileged to make it to the election among these inspiring gentlemen. :)

Comment: Actually, it *is* a particular order! But congratulations to Pedro, Daniel, and Jyrki (in no *significant* order)!

Comment: Congratulations to all new moderators and also the community!

Comment: Asaf, care to explain the round system?

Comment: @Arkamis: What do you mean?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm confused what the rounds mean and when/how they are delimited. How do the rounds differ from simply tallying the votes?

Comment: @Arkamis: Oh, that's the way STV works. The algorithm calculates some threshold for "being elected", then when sufficiently many people have been elected the rounds end. Until then you redistribute the lowest user[s]'s votes amongst the rest somehow, or the surplus from previously determined winners. It's a strange method, and I can't fully account as to how it works. But I think that this what a single *transferable* vote means, essentially.

Comment: @Arkamis There's a description [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote#Counting_the_votes). If you view the summary for this election, what's happening is any votes for someone over the threshold for winning are redistributed (or rather, all their votes are redistributed, but with a scale factor such that the right number of total votes is redistributed), and then if we don't have enough winners, the votes from the person with the fewest are redistributed. Then repeat. The rounds alternate between these two types of redistribution.

Comment: @aes Great, thanks!